# The content of element type "join" must match "(subselect?,comment?,key,(property|many-to-one|component|

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate

I know there is a very silly error with this xml file below but I am unable to fix the same. I am using mixed strategy with hibernate, and I want only one subclass as table strategy and the rest as joined.Here is the xml. I know it should be silly but I am not in xml mapping i use annotations and I am getting acquainted with xml hbms now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class table="PAYMENT" name="parent.Payment">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="PAYMENT_TYPE" type="string"/>
        <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT" />
        <subclass discriminator-value="CREDIT" 
        name="child.CreditCardPayment">
            <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
                <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE" type="string"/>
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="child.CashPayment" discriminator-value="CASH">
            <join table="CASH_PAYMENT">
                <property name="cashType" column="CATYPE" type="string"/>
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="child.ChequePayment" discriminator-value="CHEQUE">
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Exception is as such:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 11; The content of element type "join" must match "(subselect?,comment?,key,(property|many-to-one|component|dynamic-component|any)*,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the `<key column=" "/>` with `column="PAYMENT_ID"` as below:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class table="PAYMENT" name="parent.Payment">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="PAYMENT_TYPE" type="string"/>
        <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
        <subclass discriminator-value="CREDIT" 
        name="child.CreditCardPayment">
            <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
                <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
                <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE" type="string"/>
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="child.CashPayment" discriminator-value="CASH">
            <join table="CASH_PAYMENT">
                <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
                <property name="cashType" column="CATYPE" type="string"/>
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="child.ChequePayment" discriminator-value="CHEQUE">
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```